# Remove ] from string based on whether it used as index

Tags: bash, sed

Trying with sed (in bash script) to do some substring editing

```
string1=randomthing0]
string2=otherthing[15]}]
string3=reallyotherthing[5]]
```

The aim is to remove the ]s when it is not used as an index-type as in the second one. 
The output should be

```
string1=randomthing0
string2=otherthing[15]}
string3=reallyotherthing[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
s/\[\([^]]\+\)\]/@B@\1@E@/g
s/\]//g
s/@B@/[/g
s/@E@/]/g
```

It first replaces all `[...]` with `@B@...@E@`, i.t. the only remaining `]`'s are the non-balanced ones. Then, it just removes them and replaces the @-strings back.

Be careful: your input should never contain the @-strings.

Comment: The way you can deal with that is to wrap the command in `sed 's/@/@A/g' | ... script ... | sed 's/@A/@/g'` so within the script you can use @B, @C, etc. to represent whatever you like and you KNOW those could not be present in the input your script gets because every @ in your original input is succeeded by an A thanks to the first sed.

Comment: Just be aware the above script MIGHT not behave as you want for text like `the [ array[7]` since the first sed command would match `[ array[7]` rather than `[7]`. If that's a problem, change `[^]]` to `[^][]`.

Answer (score 0):

if awk is accepted as well, check the awk solution below:

```
awk  'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""}{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        s+=$i=="["?1:0; 
        e+=$i=="]"?1:0;            
        if(e>s){$i="";e--} } 
        s=e=0; print $0; }' file
```

**Note**

- the script above is NOT generic enough. it only remove unbalanced `"]"`, which means `foo[a[b[c]` won't be modified
- if there is unbalanced ], they would be deleted, no matter they are at the end of the line or not. so `foo[x]bar]blah` will be changed into `foo[x]barblah`

an example explains it better: (I added two more lines in your input)

```
#in my new lines(1,2) all "]"s surrounded with * should be removed
kent$  cat a.txt  
stringx=randomthi[foo]bar*]*xx*]*
stringy=random[f]x*]*bar[b]*]*blah
string1=randomthing0]
string2=otherthing[15]}]
string3=reallyotherthing[5]]

kent$  awk  'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""}{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        s+=$i=="["?1:0;
        e+=$i=="]"?1:0;
        if(e>s){$i="";e--} } 
        s=e=0; print $0; }' a.txt
stringx=randomthi[foo]bar**xx**
stringy=random[f]x**bar[b]**blah
string1=randomthing0
string2=otherthing[15]}
string3=reallyotherthing[5]
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([^][]*(\[[^]]*\][^][]*)*)\]/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([^\[0-9]\)\([0-9\]*\)\]/\1\2/'
```

This removes any ] which is preceded by something not in [ or 0-9 followed by zero or more 0-9 characters.